# Wildcard SSL Certifcate from GoDaddy issue started happening 6 hours ago

Tags: ssl, openssl

We have been using a Standard UCC SSL Certificate - 5 SANs for about 3 years now.  Today 1/3 of our iPhones now display "The Connection Is Not Private" with no way to continue.  I spoke with GoDaddy and they suggested I re-generate my SSL certificate and reinstall.

I am not sure how to specific the 3 SAN entries I want to associate with the SSL cert.  If I have mydomain.com as the root domain, and phonesystem.mydomain.com, webserver.mydomain.com, and testserver.mydomain.com

What would the openssl.cnf file look like??  I see lots of examples with DNS= do I just change that to SNA=?

Thank you all